# Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' even if I change user setting

Tags: mysql

```
<?php

 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','firstdb')
 or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

?>

<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>PHP connect to MySQL</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Although error says "Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost'", I can't seem to have access to my file because I get access denied for root user that doesn't have a password.

I also tried to make a user with username "username" but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Try setting a password to the root user

Comment: that;s very odd. We'd expect the error to be "**`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`**, given the code shown in the question. Why would "root" be getting replaced with "username" ?

Comment: I tried adding a password, it still shows the same error saying "Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Answer (score 0):

Nothing was wrong with the code.

I was editing a php file with the same file name of the file I try to connect on